# Winforms Textbox control that can render unreadable characters in a readable format like <CR> <LF>

Tags: .net, textbox, richtextbox

Does anyone know of a Textbox control that can render unreadable characters in a readable format like `<CR> <LF>` or something similar

It would also help if it had large file support , i.e Capable of loading large amounts of text without grinding to a halt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` is capable of that kind of rendering.

Comment: Ahh ok, would that be like just a find and replace type thing, or is there some underlying rendering i can do

Comment: That would be a find and replace type thing.  `String.Replace` should get you there.